# Importing maven web project in eclipse giving red, *, ? error in .project, .classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cometd

I have created a maven project following the guidelines of the website http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/. 
It's working fine in CMD. 
Now, i have converted this project to eclipse web project using command:
      mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

when i am importing this project to eclipse juno, it's giving some error.[image]

In project facets i have checked dynamic web module. But still i'm getting this error.

Comment: Which errors get you?

Comment: try with this command to convert `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and import it

Comment: @M.Sharma, mvn eclipse:eclipse, will only convert the project as Eclipse Java project, adding extra -Dwtpversion=2.0 argument will make it as Eclipse web project. http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete .classpath and target folders(only src and pom whould be there). without running mvn eclipse:eclipse just import like a simple maven project. Give it a try it should work